# Aggregate and fill data for missing dates (days and hours)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose we have a list like this showing the count of each object on a particular date (mm-dd-yyyy-hour-minute):

```
A = [
 [
    ['07-07-2012-21-04', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-16-2012-08-57', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-18-2012-03-30', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-18-2012-03-30', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-03-58', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-03-58', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-04-09', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-04-09', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-05-21', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-05-21', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-06-03', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-07-51', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-08-17', 'orange', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-08-17', 'orange', 1]
 ],
 [
    ['07-07-2012-21-04', 'banana', 1]
 ],
 [
    ['07-07-2012-21-04', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-16-2012-08-57', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-18-2012-03-30', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-18-2012-03-30', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-03-58', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-03-58', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-04-09', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-04-09', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-05-21', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-05-21', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-06-03', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-07-51', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-08-17', 'mango', 1],
    ['08-19-2012-08-17', 'mango', 1]
 ]
```

]

What I need to do in A is to fill all the missing dates (from minimum date to maximum date of A) for each object with value as 0. Once the missing dates and their corresponding values (0) are in, I want to sum up the values for each date, so that no date repeats - for each sublist.

Now, What I am trying to goes as follows: I am breaking up A's dates and values separately (in lists named u and v) and converting each sublist into a pandas Series, and allocating their respective indices to them. So for each zip(u,v):

```
def generate(values, indices):

    indices = flatten(indices)

    date_index = DatetimeIndex(indices)
    ts = Series(values, index=date_index)

    ts.reindex(date_range(min(date_index), max(date_index)))

    return ts
```

But in here, the reindexing is causing raising an exception. What I am looking for is a purely pythonic way (without pandas) which is totally based on either list comprehension or maybe even numpy arrays.

There is another issue of aggregation over hours, which means that if all the dates are same and only the hours are different then I want to fill in all the missing hours of the day and then repeat the same process of aggregation over each hour, with missing hours filled in with 0 values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "What I am looking for is a purely pythonic way (without pandas)" huh?

Comment: I meant to say something with list comprehension..maybe..

Comment: Instead of describing what you want with text, why not show a fake example of the kind of output you want.

Comment: @khan - is anything wrong with my answer below?? I'm waiting for your opinion more then a year and I did some effort to provide it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict                              
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                      
from itertools import chain, groupby                                          

flat = sorted((datetime.strptime(d, '%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M').date(), f, c)           
              for (d, f, c) in chain(*A))                                     
counts = [(d, f, sum(e[2] for e in l))                                        
          for (d, f), l                                                       
          in groupby(flat, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1]))]                       

# lets assume that there are some data                                        
start = counts[0][0]                                                          
end = counts[-1][0]                                                           
result = OrderedDict((start+timedelta(days=i), defaultdict(int))             
                     for i in range((end-start).days+1))                      
for day, data in groupby(counts, key=lambda d: d[0]):                         
    result[day].update((f, c) for d, f, c in data)
```

My question is: do we **really** need to fill non existing dates - I can easily imagine situation when this will be **a lot** of data, even dangerous amount of data... I think that it is better to use simple general function and generator if you want to list them somewhere:

```
from collections import defaultdict                                           
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                      
from itertools import chain, groupby                                          

def aggregate(data, resolution='daily'):                                      
    assert resolution in ['hourly', 'daily']                                  
    if resolution == 'hourly':                                                
        round_dt = lambda dt: dt.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)   
    else:                                                                     
        round_dt = lambda dt: dt.date()                                       

    flat = sorted((round_dt(datetime.strptime(d, '%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M')), f, c)    
                  for (d, f, c) in chain(*A))                                 
    counts = [(d, f, sum(e[2] for e in l))                                    
              for (d, f), l                                                   
              in groupby(flat, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1]))]
    result = {}                                                              
    for day, data in groupby(counts, key=lambda d: d[0]):                    
        d = result[day] = defaultdict(int)                                   
        d.update((f, c) for d, f, c in data)                                 
    return result                                                            

def xaggregate(data, resolution='daily'):                                      
    aggregated = aggregate(data, resolution)                                 
    curr = min(aggregated.keys())                                            
    end = max(aggregated.keys())                                             
    interval = timedelta(days=1) if resolution == 'daily' else timedelta(seconds=3600)
    while curr <= end:
        # None is sensible value in case of missing data I think                                                       
        yield curr, aggregated.get(curr)                   
        curr += interval
```

In general my suggestion is that you should not use lists as ordered structures (I mean `['07-07-2012-21-04', 'mango', 1]`). I think that `tuple` is more appropriate for this purpose and of course `collections.namedtuple` is even more desired.

Comment: I am really sorry for this delayed response. your answer is correct and it helped me out. Much thanks and respect.

Comment: "your answer (...) helped me out." That's great - I was afraid that it was useless. Thanks!